# Remove square brackets using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I'm attempting to delete square bracket and convert the strings below:

```
{"id":1","color": ["green","red", "blue"]}, {"id":2, color:black}
```

become:

```
{"id":1","color": "green,red,blue"}, {"id":2, color:black}
```

I have tried this code but still get an error :

> sed: -e expression #1, char 39: Unmatched ) or )

```
sed 's/\("color"\):[\([a-z0-9]*\)]/\1:"\2"/g'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is this a JSON array?

Comment: Since square brackets mean something to the regex interpreter, you need to escape them: `\[` and `\]`. Or at least the opening square bracket. You're also not going to match `"green","red", "blue"` with `\([a-z0-9]*\)`.

Comment: yes, it is @oguzismail

Comment: @natadecoco it's not a valid JSON array though, can you provide a valid one so we can test on it?

Comment: @lurker is it because inside group 2 doesn't contain comma? i've insert it but doesn't match

Comment: It's more complicated than just adding the comma. You have an optional space as well as multiple substrings enclosed in quotes.

Comment: There is usually something wrong with an odd number of quotation marks.

Comment: Try `sed ':a;s/\(\[[^][]*\)",[ \t]*"/\1,/;ta ; s/\("color"\):[ \t]*\[\([^][]*\)]/\1:\2/g;'`

Comment: @natadecoco It has two substitution commands: 1) replaces all `","` (or `", "`) that happen to be located after `[` and 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` with `,`, 2) your fixed expression to remove `[`  and `]` around the `color` value.

Comment: i see. thank you very much @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: You can keep asking about manipulating JSON with sed and you'll get answers, but I'd be remiss no to point out (again) that you're really setting yourself up for a lot more pain down the road. You should a) fix whatever produces the JSON and b) process JSON with a JSON aware tool such as jq, not sed.

Comment: I've read about jq and you're right. Thank you for the suggestion @Benjamin W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sed ':a;s/\(\[[^][]*\)",[ \t]*"/\1,/;ta ; s/\("color"\):[ \t]*\[\([^][]*\)]/\1:\2/g;' file > newfile
```

See the [online sed demo](https://ideone.com/vCnhwE).

**`:a;s/\(\[[^][]*\)",[ \t]*"/\1,/;ta` Details**

- `:a` - label
- `s/\(\[[^][]*\)",[ \t]*"/\1,/`:

  - `\(\[[^][]*\)` - finds and captures into Group 1 any 0 or more chars other than `]` and `[`
  - `",` - a `",` substring
  - `[^ \t]*` - zero or more chars other than space and tab
  - `"` - a `"` char
- `\1,` - replaces with the Group 1 contents + a comma
- `ta` - loop to `:a` label if there was a match at the preceding iteration.

**`s/\("color"\):[ \t]*\[\([^][]*\)]/\1:\2/g` Details**

- `\("color"\)` - matches and captures into Group 1 a `"color"` substring
- `:` - a colon
- `[ \t]*` - 0+ tabs or spaces
- `\[` -  a `[` char
- `\([^][]*\)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than `]` and `[`
- `]` - a `]` char
- `\1:\2` - replaces with Group 1 value, `:`, Group 2 value
- `g` - all occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd' file, try gnu sed:

```
sed -E 'h;s/.*\[([^]]*)\].*/\1/;s/"//g; G;s/(.*)\n(.*)\[[^]]*\](.*)/\2"\1"\3/' d
```